# Variable javascript array chartists.js

Tags: javascript

What I am trying to do with the chartist.js is allow for variable to change the values in the array which creates the chart.

So I am using the donut chart which I am using a series of 2 inside that array and 1 label.

```
    var x = 20, 
        y = 60,

    var chart = new Chartist.Pie('.ct-chart', {
          series: [x, y],
          labels: [43]
    }, {
      donut: true,
      showLabel: true
});
```

I am getting an error when trying to set the x & y variables of Uncaught `SyntaxError: Unexpected token var` I know this is a bit of a schoolboy error but I want to make sure I am doing this the right way but not sure - the end goal is to have two input boxes which I can submit two values which in turn change the chart values and create the donut chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
                <head>
                    .....
                </head>
                <body>
                    <script>
                        function onDrawClick() {
                            var x = document.getElementById("xFieldId").value;
                            var y = document.getElementById("yFieldId").value;
                            var chart = new Chartist.Pie('.ct-chart', {
                                series: [x, y],
                                labels: [43]
                            }, {
                                donut: true,
                                showLabel: true
                            });
                        }
                    </script>
                    <div class="ct-chart"></div>        
                    <input type="number" id="xFieldId">
                    <input type="number" id="yFieldId">
                    <button onclick="onDrawClick()">Show</button>
                </body>
            </html>
```

Your code with full example.

Comment: Ah brill that has done the trick! A quick question how would I add an input box to change the values of x and y? instead of having static values?

Comment: You can use two `<input type='number'  id='x_field_id'>` and use `var x=document.getElementById('x_field_id').value` to get updated value.

Comment: I am terrible with javascript - would you be able to show me an example at all?